# Select multiple sum dependent of id mysql

Tags: mysql

Using phpmyadmin
I have a table with an amount and 2 ids from 2 other tables.
One table is "tb_request" and I want to group by it's ID. The other table is "extras" and I want 2 SUMs, one if the extra is a drink and one if its not.
The select and sums work, but I want it to only do the sum for target ids.

```
SELECT tb_request_extra.id_tb_request AS "ID"
(SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM tb_request_extra
INNER JOIN tb_extra
 ON tb_request_extra.id_tb_extra = tb_extra.id
WHERE tb_extra.type="drinks") AS "drinks"
 (Same for extras)
FROM tb_request_extra
 GROUP BY tb_request_extra.id_tb_request
```

How can I do that SUM for only the currect ID? Example of a result:

```
ID.      DRINKS.     EXTRAS
1.               3.               5
2.                1.             3. 
3.                  1.             4.  
4.                  0.              0.
```

Example of what im getting:

```
ID.       DRINKS.      EXTRAS 
1.              5.                    12
 2.             5.                     12
  3.            5.                    12.  
 4.             5.                     12
```

Heres the structure
For what matters here: tb_request_extra -> id, amount, id_tb_extra, id_tb_request...... tb_extra-> id, type

Comment: What's the table structure?  What's the relationship between table?  Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you should give readable names to your tables and columns.

Comment: For what matters here: tb_r_e -> id, amount, id_tb_e, id_tb_r. tb_e-> id, type

Comment: Changed names to make it more readable

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s1.ID,s1.Drinks,s2.Extras FROM
    (SELECT tb_request_extras.id_tb_request AS 'ID', SUM(amount) AS "Drinks"
    FROM tb_request_extras
    INNER JOIN tb_extras
        ON tb_request_extras.id_tb_extras=tb_extras.id
    INNER JOIN tb_extras_type
        ON tb_extras.tb_id_extras_type=tb_extras_type.id
    WHERE tb_extras_type.extras_type="Bebidas"
    GROUP BY tb_request_extras.id_tb_request) s1
JOIN
    (SELECT  tb_request_extras.id_tb_request AS 'ID', SUM(amount) AS "Extras"
    FROM tb_request_extras
    INNER JOIN tb_extras
        ON tb_request_extras.id_tb_extras=tb_extras.id
    INNER JOIN tb_extras_type
        ON tb_extras.tb_id_extras_type=tb_extras_type.id
    WHERE tb_extras_type.extras_type!="Bebidas"
    GROUP BY tb_request_extras.id_tb_request) s2
ON s1.ID=s2.ID
```